# Big Query SQL - Group into every n numbers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that includes a column called `minutes_since`. It is an integer containing the number of minutes since a pre-defined event. Multiple rows maybe fall within the same minute.

I want to group and aggregate the rows into every n minutes. For example, I want to get the average of another column for all rows occurring within 5 minute intervals.

How could this be achieved in big query standard sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MIN(minutes_since) minute_start, 
  MAX(minutes_since) minute_end,  
  AVG(value) value_avg
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
GROUP BY DIV(minutes_since - 1, 5)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Consider also voting up the answer :o)